# react : changes on context does not re-render my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Hello everyone,

- First post on StackOverflow, and quite new to the world of Web Dev but I am working with a friend of mine to guide me. I came here because none of us seems to find the answer about an issue that I have. So here it is, hoping that I'll make myself clear enough for you to help me.
- So, I am in the process of creating my first website for a friend, it is a simple project. Where I am trying to render (and re-render) components through a context (and different changes of said context). So here is a reduced version of my project for the purpose of this question https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-https-l5c6d?file=/src/App.js
- For the context, I am trying to display an infobox (yellow square) corresponding to a planet (gray circles) everytime we click on the said planet and it should disappear everytime we click on an other planet to make an other infobox appear.

  So for this purpose I created a context with a state containing objects representing the planets and the onClick function on each planets does the job of changing a boolean which render or not the infobox.

  As seen with the console.log it does change, but it actually never re-render the components planets with the infobox on click whereas if you manually change the context it wil appear on first render. Since I see everywhere (react docs, and stackoverflow) that : "a component calling useContext will always re-render when the context value changes."

  Why is mine not re-rendering on change ?

Hoping I have made myself clear and gave enough informations.

edit : sorry to everyone, I think I have updated my sandbox, first time using it and got confused by my local storage I guess.

Comment: Try to fix the sandbox or post your code here. Without it we can only guess

Comment: Yeah my bad sorry, as I said I am quite new to this world but I think I did fix it. see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sandbox code is showing empty, though the issue may be because you aren't storing your context value within your app component's state. If you change a static value, a re-render won't be triggered.

See this working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-fermat-6ji6y?file=/src/App.js

Edit:
Your reducer was mutating state directly, change to below and it works

```
export const planetReducer = (planetsTab, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "switchPlanetToggle":
      return [
        ...planetsTab.slice(0, action.index),
        {
          ...planetsTab[action.index],
          planetToggle: !planetsTab[action.index].planetToggle
        },
        ...planetsTab.slice(action.index + 1)
      ];
    default:
      return planetsTab;
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-sea-lwwep?file=/src/PlanetsContext.js

Comment: Hi Pavlos, First of all thank you for your time, I did edit my sandbox for more info. But if I am getting what you are saying I shall useContext in my App (I use hooks btw, not classes) since I declared a state in my context whereas you did so in your app ? tbh I actually dont see why I shall destructure it in my app since I do so in my component (which is the point of context if I get it right).

Comment: Hello again, I think I get what you are doing but when done in my project it does not seems to work. Hence, I must miss something but I do not get what I actually miss. I've tried to clarify my code as much as possible for a probable futur answer. Thank you again.

Comment: The issue was with your reducer mutating state directly; see updated answer.

Comment: Okay I thank you so much. I don't really get the ins and outs of why mutating it is not 'enough' to be considered a change but if a slice does the job then a slice it will be.
Thank you again I really appreciate your help and the time you spent on my case.

Comment: Direct mutations to state aren't recorded; you have to return a new object that reflects the changes you want. Slice returns a copy and "..." is used to iterate that copy. In between the slices you are inserting the new object that reflects the change.

Comment: Fair enough ! Once again thanks a lot. You took the time to give me an exemple, to analyze (correct) my code and to explain me what is what. It is really appreciated.